# In lodash how can I deep remove?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a data structure as such at the bottom.. and I need to remove from the array the `totype.id === 'REG'` and also all instances of the object property `budgt`.

I have accomplished part of this using the following code, and was going to do another iteration to remove the `budgt` from all remaining `totype`s but that didn't seem the best way to do it.

```
_.each(data, function (d, i) { // iterate over each "org"
  _.each(d.occs, function (occ) { // iterate over each "occ" in current "org"
    return _.remove(occ.totypes, function (totype) { // remove the totype REG from "totypes"
      return totype.id === 'REG'
    })

    // how do i remove the "budgt" from each remaining totype
  })
})
```

**sample data**

```
var data = [
  {
    org: "org1",
    occs: [
      {
        name: "occ1",
        totypes: [
          {
            id: "REG",
            act: 1,
            auth: 2,
            budgt: 3
          },
          {
            id: "PRV",
            act: 1,
            auth: 2,
            budgt: 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "occ2",
        totypes: [
          {
            id: "REG",
            act: 1,
            auth: 2,
            budgt: 3
          },
          {
            id: "PRV",
            act: 1,
            auth: 2,
            budgt: 3
          }
        ]
      },
  },
  {
    org: "org2",
    occs: [
      {
        name: "occ1",
        totypes: [
          {
            id: "REG",
            act: 1,
            auth: 2,
            budgt: 3
          },
          {
            id: "PRV",
            act: 1,
            auth: 2,
            budgt: 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "occ2",
        totypes: [
          {
            id: "REG",
            act: 1,
            auth: 2,
            budgt: 3
          },
          {
            id: "PRV",
            act: 1,
            auth: 2,
            budgt: 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: just use Javasciprt delete function. Don't use lodash for everything

Comment: okay sure but I don't know about the iteration doesn't seem efficient is there a way with delete to do a deep delete ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "deep remove" the way you are describing with Lodash. It doesn't provide any querying construct like MongoDB.

Comment: would you be able to provide a better approach ?

Comment: If this is data coming from the back-end, I would look into not returning this field at all. If you have no control of that data, then you will need to loop through each object and delete it. I don't think there is a way around it.

Comment: yeah it's a payload of 20k records at the top level and client side filtering to hide show those fields dynamically. we don't really want to fetch data each time :/ and we can't do pagination because of the needs I have to show all data at once :/

Comment: have you tried using a recursive function with "unset" or "update" or "updateWith"?- perhaps that is an avenue you can go down.

Comment: James I have not tried that I'll look into that as an option.